# eval error: unknown attribute when using a PORO with data from 3rd party API rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm pulling in data from the NHL API; specifically I'm drilling down to an individual game which arrives from the API as such:

```json
{:gamePk=>2023010045,
 :link=>"/api/v1/game/2023010045/feed/live",
 :gameType=>"PR",
 :season=>"20232024",
 :gameDate=>"2023-09-29T00:30:00Z",
 :status=>{:abstractGameState=>"Preview", :codedGameState=>"1", :detailedState=>"Scheduled", :statusCode=>"1", :startTimeTBD=>false},
 :teams=>
  {:away=>{:leagueRecord=>{:wins=>0, :losses=>0, :type=>"league"}, :score=>0, :team=>{:id=>19, :name=>"St. Louis Blues", :link=>"/api/v1/teams/19"}},
   :home=>{:leagueRecord=>{:wins=>0, :losses=>0, :type=>"league"}, :score=>0, :team=>{:id=>16, :name=>"Chicago Blackhawks", :link=>"/api/v1/teams/16"}}},
 :venue=>{:id=>5092, :name=>"United Center", :link=>"/api/v1/venues/5092"},
 :content=>{:link=>"/api/v1/game/2023010045/content"}}
```

I'm looking to turn this data into a PORO:

```rb
class Game

  attr_reader :start_time, :home_team, :away_team

  def initialize(data)
    @start_time = data[:gameDate].to_datetime.strftime("%F")
    @home_team = data[:teams][:home][:team][:name]
    @away_team = data[:teams][:away][:team][:name]
  end
end
```

When I run `Game.new(game)`, I get one of two following errors:

`eval error: unknown attribute 'gamePk' for Game.`

or

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'gamePk' for Game.`

I've made no reference to `:gamePk` in my PORO, so why is Rails even looking at the `:gamePk` key/value pair in the original json?

I've done this before in Rails 5 and Rails 6....I have no desire to persist this data to a database, since it's already being persisted somewhere else.

#### My question:

Why is Rails throwing an error for `:gamePk` when my PORO makes no reference to that data?

## Edit:

### The backtrace, as requested:

```
eval error: unknown attribute 'gamePk' for Game.

          raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k.to_s)
          ^^^^^
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.7/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:21:in `block in _assign_attributes'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:13:in `each'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:13:in `_assign_attributes'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.7/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:34:in `assign_attributes'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:468:in `initialize'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:75:in `new'
  /Users/jrbobbdobbs/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:75:in `new'
  (rdbg)//Users/jrbobbdobbs/Documents/projects/sites/hockey/ChicagoBlackhawks/app/facades/game_facade.rb:1:in `block in create_games'
```

Comment: the default behavior of `initialize` is to attempt to assign the values in a hash to attributes.  I've seen this happen before when `initialize` has been misspelled -- the custom method created never gets called, but the base method does instead.

Comment: @dbugger Thanks for the comment; I considered that and confirmed that I am in fact spelling `initialize` correctly. The code above is copy/pasted from my project. Unless I'm missing something obvious....

Comment: I suspect the `data` object you're passing in is not a simple hash.  You don't say how you're initializing/collecting it.  Nor do you provide a full backtrace - what line is actually failing?

Comment: @kwerle the data object is the first hash listed above at the top of my post; I've now added the stacktrace as an edit; thanks for the eyeballs; It's being collected via a 3rd party API call, and then I'm drilling down into the JSON to get that hash

Comment: you don't happen to have an activerecord model named Game defined in the project?

Comment: Oh my god! Get out of my computer! lol! Yes I do! lol; wow.

Comment: That's your problem -- not using the model you expect.

Comment: yeah, thanks; I removed the table from the schema and the model from `app/`; This was one of my first experiences of name collision... great catch. Not sure what I should do to resolve this question

Comment: close it and call it a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @dbugger for catching this name collision issue.

Leaving for others who may experience a similar issue.

I had created a PORO with the same name as a model within my app.

After removing the `games` table from the schema, and deleting the `app/models/game.rb`, I was able to move forward as expected.